# What happened to Bonjour in Safari 11 and how do I access it?

Tags: safari, bonjour

I need to access Bonjour to get information from my printer and wonder where Bonjour has gone from Safari version 11.

Answer (score 3):

In their wisdom, Apple have removed it without providing a direct workaround. In the meantime, you can use something like [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/), which is less convenient but will at least get you to the right URLs for admin UIs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Apple clearly removed that item from the Safari menu.

My take on this is everyone is wondering about Safari 11 and Bonjour.  There is a suggestion that Apple needs to be reminded that it is huge to have Bonjour in Safari to manage printers, access scanners, even see some HomeKit device tech interfaces.

Everyone trusted Apple on Bonjour... and Safari is the preeminent end user tool to use and be introduced to the benefits of Bonjour...

consider posting your opinion on Safari-sans-Bonjour at:

Bonjour Feedback: https://www.apple.com/feedback/bonjour.html

Comment: Typical Apple, they thing they know everything better. Truly insanity and a form of arrogance that you cant understand. While not me.

Comment: To some degree, Apple is an accidental success.

Comment: Bonjour feedback link is gone at Apple.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use this Safari Extension to bring back the functionality: https://bonjourbrowser.com

Comment: As of 2023-01-01 this is priced at $2.99

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via `System Preferences` | `Printers & Scanners`.  Access the `Options & Supplies` button

[image]

Then select this button

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: The part about the printer or the part about Bonjour in Safari?